# How to create a li with a hyperlink inside VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i just want to know How to create a li  with a hyperlink inside   Visual Basic

Comment: Inside visual basic what?  Form, Page, etc?  Your question is severely under-documented.

Comment: You're going to get a more cooperative community here if you post what you tried, and maybe the errors that you are getting. Try to post a snippet and then we can point out what needs fixin'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<ul>
   <li><asp:HyperLink id="HyperLink1" runat="server" NavigateUrl="~/Default.aspx" /></li>
</ul>
```